# PostgreSQL query to iterate through array and perform product calculation on each cell

Tags: arrays, postgresql, filter

I have a cell with an array of integers (column created using the syntax: `some_arrays integer[]`)

```
    | id |   some_arrays   |
    |----+-----------------|
    | 0  |  10, 15, 20, 25 |
    |----+-----------------|
    | 1  |  1, 3, 5, 7     |
    |----+-----------------|
    | 2  |  33, 674, 2, 4  |
    |----+-----------------|
```

For any given row, I want to iterate through each array and for each element return the product of all the elements in the array other than itself.

ex:

```
some_arrays[0]
  -> [10, 15, 20, 25]
  -> [15 * 20 * 25, 10 * 20 * 25, 10 * 15 * 25, 10 * 15 * 20]
  -> [7500, 5000, 3750, 3000]
```

In Python we could do something like:

```
def get_prod(array, n):
    prod = 1
    # calculate prod all elements in array
    for i in range(n):
        prod *= array[i]
    # replace each element by the product divided by that element
    for i in range(n):
        array[i] = prod // array[i]

array = [10, 15, 20, 25]
n = len(array)
get_prod(array, n)
for i in range(n):
    print(array[i], end=" ")
```

In postgreSQL what's the correct query to select a cell, iterate through each element, and obtain the product of the other elements?

Doubling each element of each cell and displaying it to a new column is possible:

```
SELECT id, (SELECT SUM(a) FROM unnest(some_arrays) AS a) AS total FROM this_table;
SELECT some_arrays,
  ARRAY(SELECT x * 2
        FROM unnest(some_arrays) AS x) AS doubles
FROM table;
```

This yields:

```
|   some_arrays   |   doubled       | 
|-----------------+-----------------
|  10, 15, 20, 25 |  20, 30, 40, 50 | 
|-----------------+-----------------| 
|  1, 3, 5, 7     |  2, 6, 10, 14   | 
|-----------------+-----------------| 
|  66, 674, 2, 4  |  33, 1348, 4, 8 | 
|-----------------+-----------------|
```

(Using Postgres 11.10)

Thank you for any tips on writing a comprehensive for loop!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicit looping would be one way to approach this task, but I prefer to use relational calculus,

postgresql doesn't now how to do a product aggregate, but you can teach it:

```
create aggregate product(integer)
   (stype=bigint,sfunc=int84mul,initcond=1);
```

Here int84mul is a built-in function multiplies an 8 byte integer by a 4 byte integer. it's not described in the documentations but is visiblwe via instrospection eg

the psql command `\dfS+ *mul*`

then

```
select cell.*, product(a) 
from cell, 
  lateral unnest(some_arrays) as a group by 1,2 order by 1;
```

id |  some_arrays  |   exclusive_products
----+---------------+------------------------
0 | {10,15,20,25} | {7500,5000,3750,3000}
1 | {1,3,5,7}     | {105,35,21,15}
2 | {33,674,2,4}  | {5392,264,88968,44484}

will get you the result:

```
 id |  some_arrays  | product 
----+---------------+---------
  0 | {10,15,20,25} |   75000
  1 | {1,3,5,7}     |     105
  2 | {33,674,2,4}  |  177936
```

this is close.

if you then divide the product by the cell.

```
with b as (
       select cell.*, product(a) 
       from cell,
          lateral unnest(some_arrays) as a group by 1,2 )
select id,some_arrays, 
   ARRAY(SELECT product / x FROM unnest(some_arrays) AS x)
 AS exclusive_products from b order by 1;
```

gets the result

```
 id |  some_arrays  |   exclusive_products   
----+---------------+------------------------
  0 | {10,15,20,25} | {7500,5000,3750,3000}
  1 | {1,3,5,7}     | {105,35,21,15}
  2 | {33,674,2,4}  | {5392,264,88968,44484}
```

Comment: Are you able to say anything more about the built-in function int84mul? For instance, why does this multiplication function require specifically an 8 byte or a 4 byte integer?  @Jasen

Comment: products tend to big numbers, so I chose a "bigint" to hold the product,  regular integers are 4 bytes.

Comment: there are several other multiplication functions, this one is tuned for multiplying `bigint` by `integer`  postgresql uses it internally when it is evaluating arithmetic expressions.

Comment: thank you, it's always good to understand what's going on behind the query